# C# IEnumerable methods equivalents in Java List

Tags: java, c#

How to write this logic, made in C#, in Java?

```
var posicoes = await _serviceProduto.BuscarClienteProduto(_userId, _userTipo, null, null);
var clientes = await _service.BuscarCliente(_userId, _userTipo, null);

var t = clientes.Where(a => !posicoes.Any(b => b.ClienteId == a.ClienteId)).ToList();
return Ok(t);
```

Whats the type of "var t"? The return of "BuscarClienteProduto" or "BuscarCliente"?

I'm doing something like this (it has some compiling errors):

Do you have any idea of what method is equivalent for "Any()"?
Or should I make it all diffent?

```
List<CustomerProductResponse> posicoes = customerProductService.getClienteProduto(null, idUser, _userTipo, null);
List<CustomerResponse> clientes = customerService.getCliente(null, idUser, _userTipo);

List<CustomerResponse> lista = clientes.stream()
                .filter(a -> !posicoes.xxx(b -> b.clienteId == a.clienteId))
                .map(b -> new CustomerResponse(b))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Try `posicoes.stream().noneMatch(b -> Objects.equals(a.getClientedId(), b.getClientedId())`

Comment: Whats the type of "var t"? The return of "BuscarClienteProduto" or "BuscarCliente"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is `anyMatch`. You can use it as below:

```java
List<CustomerResponse> lista = clientes.stream()
    .filter(a -> !posicoes.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.clienteId == a.clienteId))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:** Removed the `map` as it should not be necessary. The original C# code posted in the question does not have a `Select` either, which would be the equivalent to Java's `map`.

You can check more details in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

You may also use `noneMatch`, to avoid the negation. Details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Comment: anyMatch() solved the problem but I have another one now. The "b" it's a CustomerResponse object type. So doesnt make sense a constructor with itself on parameter. " new CustomerResponse(b) ". Is it necessary?

Comment: If `b` is already a `CustomerResponse` you should not need it, you can get rid of the `map` line. In your original C# code you also don't have a `Select`. Java `map` and C# `Select` are the same thing. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Whats the type of "var t"? The return of "BuscarClienteProduto" or "BuscarCliente"?

Comment: In your C# code, the LINQ query is simply applying a condition on top of `BuscarCliente` results and then materializing to a list using `ToList`. Thus, the `var t` type is the same of `BuscarCliente`. The same happens in the Java case, in which the result is a `List<CustomerResponse>`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will put the class in C# and JAVA for you to see my problem.

Comment: Following the good practices, since your first question about `Any` is answered, I strongly suggest you post a different question if you have a different problem instead of editing this one.

Comment: rph I just posted another question. Thank you!